# Batch HTTP download standard

Tags: http, download-manager

I have multiple files available on HTTP server which users can download and I want to provide a single download link which will allow the user to one click download multiple files (using just web browser or download manager). The files are very big so packing them into archives on the fly and providing zip download is not an option.

Is there any combination of internet standard plus download manager which will allow for such batch HTTP downloads?

I know there is [metalink](http://www.metalinker.org/)([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalink)) standard, but it doesn't seem to be very popular and there are almost no client application supporting it:

- [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) - soon can be discontinued because Mozilla is going to deprecate their XUL extension API
- [aria2c](https://aria2.github.io/) - although works great is a command line only client which is not really user friendly

Torrent I would guess can't be used with simple HTTP download, they require torrent protocol, right?

Do you know any other alternative, except inventing own standard and/or writing own download manager?